# Quadratic equation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, quadratics, education

i have a multiple choice question

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the real root of The quadratic equation $x^2-(c+3)x+9=0$ if $x_1<-2$ and $x_2<-2$, then ......

(a) $c<\frac{-19}{2}$ or $c>9$

(b) $\frac{-19}{2}<c\le-9$

(c) $\frac{-19}{2}<c\le-7$

(d) $-9<c<3$

(e) $c>3$

and the correct answer is (b) , here is the solution, we know that based from the quadratic equations,

$x^2-(c+3)x+9=0$ $\dots(L_1)$

$x_1+x_2=c+3$ and $x_1 x_2=9$

then we know that $x_1<-2$ and $x_2<-2$ this implies

$x_1+2 < 0$ and $x_2+2<0$

then when we add it we obtain ,

$x_1+x_2+4<0$

$c+3+4<0$ , then we get

$c<-7$ $\dots (H_1)$

when we multiply it we obtain ,

$(x_1+2)(x_2+2)>0$

$x_1x_2+2(x_1+x_2)+4>0$

$9+2(c+3)+4>0$ then we will obtain

$c>\frac{-19}{2}$ $\dots (H_2)$

Now, since we are given the roots must be $x_1<-2$ and $x_2<-2$ of $(L_1)$ this means it can be either have a twin roots or two distinct root so this means the discriminant must be larger or equal to zero

$D\geq0$

$(-(c+3))^2-4.1.9 \geq 0$

$c^2+6c+9-36 \geq 0$

$c^2+6c-27 \geq 0$

$(c-3)(c+9) \geq 0$

so to satisfy the equation , $c\leq-9$ or $c\geq3$ $\dots(H_3)$

So the value of $c$ must be the intersection of $(H_!)$,$(H_2)$,$(H_3)$ which is $\frac{-19}{2}<c\le-9$

so the answer is (b)

However, i am still not clear about the question and the logic order of this solution , this question seems like asking what is the value of c so that the value of $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be always less than-2.However the question says "if $x_1<-2$ and $x_2<-2$" that means , that we are given $x_1<-2$ and $x_2<-2$ then it will give a lot of implication of $c$ . This question seems like we do the converse proof , we finding the value of c then it imply the roots are less than 2. i am really confuse about it . the second one is , we are given this condition $x_1+2<0$ and $x_2+2<0$ . then we try to solving the value of c by adding it and multiply it , my question is ,  how does this step ("by adding it and multiply it") can guarantee the value of c so that the value of $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be always less than -2 ? i dont get it . When i analyze the solution and graph seems like they asking what condition of c so that the roots are always less than -2 .

Comment: Could you punctuate, capitalise, and generally rewrite your question clearer? Doing so will increase the chance of getting answers.

Comment: As written, both answers (b) and (c) are correct. (b) gives the minimal range of $c$ for which the conditions on $x_1$ and $x_2$ are satisfied, but whenever (b) is true, (c) is also true.

Comment: No , if you take c=-8 then it Will have two complex roots

Comment: I mean , this question is seems unclear  , this is not following the mathematical logic when i see the solution. The question said if(condition ) then what happens to c ? .However when i see the solution and analyze it by the graph , the question seems like asking "what condition of c so that x1 and x2 is always less than 2 . Because if the question only ask : if x1 and x2 less than c then it Will gives you a lot of implications , the answer it could be the union of H1 H2 H3

Comment: Why they write the question like that instead " what condition of c so that x1 and x2 are less than -2" . That's more easier and the solution is acceptable .

Comment: The statement "If $x=1$ then $x$ is an integer"  is a true statement even though there are integers that are not equal to $1$

Answer (score 1):

> $x^2 - (c+3)x + 9 = 0.$ 
> The roots are $x_1, x_2,$ which may or may not be distinct. 
> $x_1 < -2, x_2 < -2.$

As I interpret the question, it is asking for all values of $c$ that will satisfy the above constraints.

I would have worded the solution differently.

First of all, you know that 
$x_1 + x_2 = (c + 3) \implies (c + 3) < -4 \implies c < -1.$

Second of all, you know that the two roots are real, which implies that 
$(c + 3)^2 \geq (4 \times 9) = 6^2 \implies c \leq -9,$ 
since it has been established that $c$ must be negative.

So, the problem is reduced to determining for which values of $c$ that are $\leq -9,$ will the two roots, $x_1$ and $x_2$ **both** be $< -2.$

---

To determine this, the quadratic formula must be applied.

Then,

$$x_1, x_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[(c + 3) \pm \sqrt{(c+3)^2 - 36}\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \left[(c + 3) \pm \sqrt{c^2 + 6c - 27}\right]. \tag1 $$

At this point, since $c \leq -9,$ it is obvious that the root represented by

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[(c + 3) - \sqrt{c^2 + 6c - 27}\right]$$

will definitely be $< -2.$

Consequently, the entire problem has been reduced to determining for which values of $c \leq -9$, will the following root **also** be $< -2$:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[(c + 3) + \sqrt{c^2 + 6c - 27}\right].  \tag2 $$

---

To attack (2) above, I first clear the $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$ fraction, and isolate the expression under the radical.

Thus,

$$(c + 3) + \sqrt{c^2 + 6c - 27} < -4 \implies   $$

$$\sqrt{c^2 + 6c - 27} < -4 - (c + 3) = -(7+c).   \tag3 $$

Examining (3) above, I note that under the constraint that $c \leq -9,$ the LHS and RHS are both non-negative numbers.  Further, I know that (in general), if $0 \leq r,s$ then $r < s \iff r^2 < s^2$.  So, I can attack (3) above by squaring both sides.

This implies that I am looking for the values of $c \leq -9$ such that

$$c^2 + 6c - 27 < c^2 + 14c + 49 \iff -76 < 8c.$$

This simplies to a lower bound for $c$ of

$$\frac{-19}{2} = \frac{-76}{8} < c.$$

Answer (score 0):

1st question - You're asking why we find a value of c first, then we take discriminants right? It feels like extra working to you?

The first part of the proof is basically coming up with a value that satisfies the first few conditions. In this instance, you found that $\frac{-19}{2}$ < c < -7.

Even though this gives a value of c, it only gives values of c that satisfies the conditions above. **It does not take into consideration whether roots exist when c is in the range you've found**. For example, c = -8 is within the range of -19/2 < c < -7, [but the graph looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06GG5.png)

As you can see, this graph has **no roots**, which is nonsense because obviously the real roots exist. Therefore, we need the discriminants to make sure that **the c values that we have give a graph with real roots**. Doing discriminants, we get a second range that we can use to find a value of c that

(1) Meets the required conditions

(2) Has real roots that exist.

qn 2 - Asking about why we add and multiply

Well, you have the values for x1 + x2 and x1x2 right? And these are the only 2 values you have, so you need to use them to find the value of c. The only way to make x1x2 is to **multiply them together** and x1 + x2 is found by **adding them together**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I mean , this question is seems unclear , this is not following the mathematical logic when i see the solution. The question said if(condition ) then what happens to c ? .However when i see the solution and analyze it by the graph , the question seems like asking "what condition of c so that x1 and x2 is always less than 2 . Because if the question only ask : if x1 and x2 less than c then it Will gives you a lot of implications , the answer it could be the union of H1 H2 H3

Comment: Why they write the question like that instead " what condition of c so that x1 and x2 are less than -2" . That's more easier and the solution is acceptable .